# In Angular 13.3 version , angular tests are not failing even after compile error in typescript file, getting 0 of 0 SUCCESS

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular13

I have migrated the project from angular 8 to angular 13.3 , after that when i run my jasmine test with ng test , even if i have compilation error in the spec.ts file , my test is showing success and not failing at all , and does not executes further tests as well.

getting 0 of 0 SUCCESS

as per my expectation it should fail the test and should not skip further tests .
Is there any workaround i can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you go onto https://localhost:9876 and open your web-console do you see any errors?

Comment: No i cannot see the errors on web console , it just says "Incomplete: No specs found, , randomized with seed 18676", but i can see error on command prompt where i am running ng test command.